# Обращение к синхронизированным методам из двух потоков

Tags: java, многопоточность

Начал изучать Java по книге Шилдта (Java 8 Полное рук-во 9изд).
В теме по многопоточному программированию сказано:

[image]
Т.е получается 2 потока не могут одновременно работать с синхронизированными методами объекта.
Написав код, чтобы проверить:

```
//T1, T2 - потоки
//q объект класса Q, с которым работают потоки
//В потоке Т1 50 раз должно вывестисть One
//В потоке T2 50 раз должно вывестисть Two
class Q{
   synchronized void print1(){
      System.out.println("One");
   }
   synchronized void print2(){
      System.out.println("Two");
   }
}
class T1 implements Runnable{
   Q q;
   T1(Q q){
      this.q = q;
      new Thread(this).start();
   }
   public void run(){
      for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++){
         q.print1();
      }
   }
}
class T2 implements Runnable{
   Q q;
   T2(Q q){
      this.q = q;
      new Thread(this).start();
   }
   public void run(){
      for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++){
         q.print2();
      }
   }
}
public class main {
   public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException{
      Q q = new Q();
      new T1(q);
      new T2(q);

   }
}
```

у меня получилось следующее:

```
...
One
One
Two
Two
Two
One
One
...
```

Почему происходит переключение с одного потока на другой и обратно? Нет ли тут противоречия тому, что написано в книге? Методы синхронизированные и получается 2ой поток должен ждать, когда 1ый поток завершит работу с объектом или я что-то не так понял?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Они не могут одновременно выполняться. А последовательно выполняться они могут.

1. `T1` вызывает `print1()` и тем самым блокирует объект.
2. `T2` вызывает `print2()`, но объект блокирован и `T2` ждет.
3. `T1` выходит из `print1()` и разблокирует объект.
4. `T2` начинает выполнять `print2()` и блокирует объект.
5. Процесс повторяется.

Но не обязательно все будет происходить поочередно. Может быть ситуация, что один из потоков будет чаще выполнятся, а другой реже. Это не предсказуемо.