# Как работают lock объекты?

Tags: java, многопоточность

Я пытаюсь разобраться с логикой лок-объектов на нескольких примерах,
речь всегда пойдет об одном экземпляре `MyClass`:

Пример 1:

Если поток один зайдет в метод `a()`, то поток два в метод `b()`, уже войти не сможет, пока первый поток из метода `a()`, не выйдет? Потому что объект монитор у нас один и тот-же? Или не правильно?

```
MyClass {
    final Object obj = new Object();

    void a() {
        synchronized(obj) {
            // do something...
        }
    }

    void b() {
        synchronized(obj) {
            // do something...
        }
    }
}
```

Пример 2:

Если поток один зайдет в метод `a()`, то поток два в метод `b()`, войти сможет. Потому что объекты мониторов у нас разные. Или не правильно?

```
MyClass {
    final Object obj1 = new Object();
    final Object obj2 = new Object();

    void a() {
        synchronized(obj1) {
            // do something...
        }
    }

    void b() {
        synchronized(obj2) {
            // do something...
        }
    }
}
```

Пример 3:

Если поток один зайдет в метод `a()`, то поток два в метод `b()`, уже войти не сможет, пока первый поток из метода `a()`, не выйдет? Потому что объект монитор у нас один и тот-же? Как в примере один.

Значит ли это, что я могу спокойно обращаться к методам `read` и `write`, и быть уверенным что потери данных, из-за гонки, или кэширования не произойдет?

```
MyClass {
    final Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();

    void a() {
    String read(final String key, final String value) {
        synchronized(map) {
            this.map.put(key, value);
        }
    }

    String write(final String key) {
        synchronized(map) {
            return this.map.get(key);
        }
    }
}
```

Пример 4:

Будет ли являться такой код потокобезопасным в ситуации, если обращаться к методам `read` и `write`, из разных потоков? Почему? Что может произойти?

```
MyClass {
    volatile Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    final Object readLock = new Object();
    final Object writeLock = new Object();

    String read(final String key, final String value) {
        synchronized(readLock) {
            this.map.put(key, value);
        }
    }

    String write(final String key) {
        synchronized(writeLock) {
            return this.map.get(key);
        }
    }
}
```

Спасибо.

Comment: может быть вот эти ответы помогут http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/611216/215007 http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/620551/215007

Comment: не стоит задавать несколько вопросов в одном - это затрудняет поиск.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disclaimer: **формально** оба потока смогут зайти в любые методы во всех примерах - они могут остановиться на synchronized-блоке, который расположен внутри метода. Понятно, что интересовала именно синхронизация, поэтому дальше идет речь исключительно про блокировку одного потока другим в критической секции.

> 1. Если поток один зайдет в метод a(), то поток два в метод b() уже войти не сможет, пока первый поток из метода a() не выйдет? Потому что объект монитор у нас один и тот же?

Да, все верно.

> 2. Если поток один зайдет в метод a(), то поток два в метод b() войти сможет. Потому что объекты мониторов у нас разные.

Тоже все верно.

> 3. Если поток один зайдет в метод a(), то поток два в метод b() уже войти не сможет, пока первый поток из метода a() не выйдет?

Да, но здесь нужно быть очень аккуратным (и, возможно, я даже ошибусь с написанием этого ответа). Порядок операций в Java определяет Java Memory Model, из которой проистекает отношение happens-before, которым и нужно оперировать для определения порядка видимости изменений: happens-before между операциями X и Y гарантирует, что результат операции Х будет виден последующей операции Y (X happens before Y -> "X происходит до Y"). Сам по себе Map/HashMap не определяет отношение hb, но у Java есть следующие обязательные отношения hb:

- Каждое последующее выражение внутри одного потока имеет отношение happens-before к предыдущему
- Выход из synchronized-блока и последующий вход имеют отношение happens-before
- Для hb(a, b) и hb(b, c) действует отношение hb(a, c)

Насколько понимаю, данный подход безопасен, но лучше сразу завернуть целиком метод в synchronized и/или взять ConcurrentHashMap - если интересно, почему я ттак беспокоюсь, можно почитать легко находимые статьи про double checked locking, в которых описывается похожий случай, который не работает. К сожалению, у меня сейчас нет времени, чтобы ответить на этот вопрос твердо и точно, общим подходом в таких случаях является better safe than sorry и жертва теоретической производительности в пользу гарантий.

> 4. Будет ли являться такой код потокобезопасным в ситуации, если обращаться к методам read и write из разных потоков?

Нет, потому что он определяет отдельно порядок чтений и отдельно порядок записи. Здесь нет отношений hb от записи к чтению, поэтому поток совершенно точно вправе увидеть любой мусор.

---

Позволю себе минуту брюзжания:

> тот-же

Тот же

> Или не правильно

неправильно

> поток два в метод b(), уже войти не сможет
>
> первый поток из метода a(), не выйдет
>
> поток два в метод b(), войти сможет
>
> поток два в метод b(), уже войти не сможет
>
> поток из метода a(), не выйдет
>
> обращаться к методам read и write, из разных потоков

Ни одна из этих запятых не нужна, здесь практически везде подлежащее-сказуемое, и между ними запятые (без дополнительных оборотов и прочих усложнений) не ставятся

> потери данных, из-за гонки, или кэширования

здесь другой случай, но тоже не нужны

Comment: Большое спасибо очень развернутый ответ, эти запятые служат интонационной выразительности)))) чес слово!!!))) Я только в одном месте не понял: Для hb(a, b) и hb(b, c) действует отношение hb(a, c) не уточните это о чем?

Comment: >>>Понятно, что интересовала именно синхронизация, поэтому дальше идет речь исключительно про взаимную блокировку в критической секции.<<< нет я пока до дедлоков не добрался мне надо просто Visabilyty и Race condition избежать.

Comment: @Павел если операции А и Б имеют отношение hb (Б всегда видит результат А), и Б и В имеют такое же отношение (В всегда видит результат Б), то существует отношение hb между A и В (В всегда видит результат А, потому что видит результат Б, который якобы был получен после результата А). В реальности операции могут быть перепутаны, но JVM в этом случае гарантирует то, что в нужной операции будут видны требуемые результаты, проще всего это представить в виде временной шкалы (что на самом деле не очень правильно): А -> Б -> В.

Comment: @Павел про взаимную блокировку - это мое косноязычие, имелось в виду блокирование одним потоком другого.

Answer (score 0):

1. Да
2. Да
3. Да
4. Нет, не будет, объекты для блокировки разные, как в примере 2. Произойдет *что-угодно*, так как хеш-таблица может прийти в некорректное состояние. Если чуть сложнее, то в Java есть модель памяти, которая может точно сказать какое поведение будет. Но состояние таблицы в любом случае может быть нарушено.

Если хотите, быстрые read/write блокировки, то можно использовать [ReentrantReadWriteLock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html).

Comment: По поводу четвертого пункта, я правильно понимаю что вы говорите про JMM если до та вы имеете в виду что проблема в Visabilyty тоесть данные могут оказаться в CPU Register или CPU Cash Memory но я указал что переменная volatile. Значит вы имеете в виду что произойдет Race condition?

Comment: @Павел volatile обеспечивает корректную запись/чтение только самого поля map, но не полей содержащегося в нем объекта.